# Tables Off the Top of the Relationship Canvas

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

Several of my tables are off the top of the relationship canvas where I cannot scroll to.

How do I access those tables and pull them back down into the usable canvas area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can only be done with a lot of API calls re-positioning the windows. An easier way would just to delete the current relationship layout (there is a button in the ribbon) and then display all relationships (another button).

This will display all tables that have a relationship, though you have to rearrange them again. But everything will be visible.

NOTE: None of your relationships will be touched, this affects just the layout!